# App directing to the page from the menu is stuck only on iPhone15

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin.ios, ios17

When I press a page in the menu, the App will start running a loading icon and directing to a new page.
But when I used iPhone15(iOS17) to do so, the App got stuck, the loading icon just kept running but the App did not jump to the new page. Wait for more than 10 minutes, the App is still the same.

The issue will only be encountered on iPhone15+iOS17, I have tried iPhone14+iOS17 works fine. And iOS11 to iOS16 all are fine.

Does anyone know how to deal with it?

Comment: please put some code in order to check your issue

Comment: Is your Xcode version 15? Does your project work properly on the iOS17 simulator? And can you provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)？

Comment: Hi all, the issue has been fixed after upgrading the package 'Xamarin.Forms' from V5.0.0.2012 to V5.0.0.2612. Thanks.